# Differences between functions and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Is there any difference between how we treat sub-sequential limits of a sequence and a function? can it be argued the same for a sequence that the set of sub-sequential limits of a function is also closed ?

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Let $f: D \to \mathbb R$ be a bounded function. Let $c$ be an accumulation point of $D$. Let $S$ be the set of all subsequential limits of $f$ at $c$, that is, the set of all limits of sequences $f(x_n)$, $x_n\in D$, such that $x_n \to c$. Prove that $S$ is closed.

Comment: What exactly do you take a "sub-sequential limit" of a function to mean?

Comment: @Henning limits of all of its sub sequcences , say for a function f(x) , what i infer as subsequential limits is the limits of all f($x_n)

Comment: x @Man: Without any restrictions on which kind of sequence $(x_n)$ can be? It could be increasing, decreasing, constant, bounded, unbounded ...? In that case a number would be a subsequential limit iff it is in the closure of the range of $f$.

Comment: @henning the function is a bounded function on R.

Comment: x @Man: I'm not asking about the _function_, but about the _sequence_ of $x_n$s that you take limits over.

Comment: I am trying to solve this question but am clueless. Let f: D -> R be a bounded function.Let c be an accumulation point of D. Let S be the set of all subsequential limits of f at c, that is , the set of all limits of sequences f(xn) ,xn belongs to D, such that xn -> c. Prove that S is closed

Comment: Oh, so you don't actually have a concept of "subsequential limit of $f$", but one of "subsequential limit of $f$ **at** c".

Comment: Ya sorry just now i realised it.i am new to analysis.Could you please help in this regard?

Comment: You posted a comment to me at [Prove that the set consisting limits of a function is closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535967/prove-that-the-set-consisting-limits-of-a-function-is-closed?), which is a closed question and hence comments are disabled and for this reason I'm answering your question here. See the proof that I gave for sequences [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=9734677). I think a simple modification of that proof will show that the set of all subsequence limits of a function at a point forms a closed set.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro Could you please elaborate on the proof?on how the proof is different for function when compared to sequences ?i am not able to get that part

Comment: @Man: I believe it's essentially an ${\epsilon}/2$ argument. Let $y_1,$ $y_2,$ etc. be limits of the function $f$ at some point $x,$ and assume $y_n \rightarrow y.$ Then we want to show that $y$ is also a limit of $f$ at $x.$ We know there is a sequence in the domain of $f$ that has limit $x$ such that the $f$-values of the terms of this sequence approach $y_1.$ Pick a term in this sequence, call it $x_1,$ such that $|f(x_1) - y_1| < 1/2.$ Do a similar thing with a sequence with limit $x$ such that the $f$-values approach $y_2$ and pick a term in this sequence, **(continued)**

Comment: **(continued)** call it $y_2,$ such that $|f(x_2) - y_2| < 1/4.$ Keep going, getting $x_3$ such that $|f(x_3) - y_3| < 1/8,$ $\ldots,$ getting $x_n$ such that $|f(x_n) - y_n| < 1/2^n,$ etc. The $\epsilon/2$ argument should now suggest itself --- the $f(x_n)$'s get really close to the $y_n$'s and the $y_n$'s get really close to $y,$ so the $f(x_n)$'s get really close to $y$ and we also have $x_n \rightarrow x$ (actually, you might have to build in some additional constraints in picking the $x_n$'s to have this happen), so it follows that $y$ is a limit of $f$ at $x.$

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a proof of the corresponding property about the set of limits of subsequences of a given sequence, it is likely that a very similar proof for this exercise can be made.

However, whether this is actually the case depends on the details of the proof you already have -- there are *some* things you can do with subsequences that you can't also do with limits in $\mathbb R$. For example if you construct a series of indices $i_n\in\mathbb N$ such that $i_n > i_{n-1}$ for all $n$, then you get automatically that $i_n\to\infty$. In the function case, it does *not* automatically happen that if you construct $(x_n)$ such that $|x_n-c|<|x_{n-1}-c|$ then $x_n\to c$. So it depends on a closer inspection.

---

For your particular exercise I would start like this:

> A set is closed if it contains all of its limit points, so let $s$ be an arbitary limit point of $S$, and we seek to prove that $s\in S$. In order to to that we must find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to c$ and $f(x_n)\to s$.
>
> These two conditions don't help much to structure what we have to do, so let's impose some stronger constraints that will help lead the way. In particular we will require that $|x_n-c|<1/n$ and that $|f(x_n)-s|<1/n$ for all $n$. This will ensure that the desired limits exist with the right value.
>
> We need to show that we can always find such an $x_n$, no matter what $n$ is.
>
> For a given $n$, since $s$ is a limit point of $S$, there will exist an $y\in S$ such that $|y-s|<1/2n$. Since $y\in S$, by definition there is a sequence $(x'_n)$ such that $x'_n\to c$ and $f(x'_n)\to y$. We can therefore find $N$ such that ...

*Note:* The assumption that $f$ is bounded is not neccesary. Neither is it necessary to assume that $c$ is an accumulation point of $D$ -- if it isn't it simply means that there are no qualifying $(x_n)$ sequences, so $S$ is the empty set, and that is certainly closed!

Comment: Could you please explain the use of the constraints you imposed ?Also y there should exist a y point like that ?

Comment: @Man: The $1/n$ (and $1/2n$) give you an $\epsilon$ to plug into the definition of convergence for the $(x'_n)$ sequences. And $y$ exists because $s$ is assumed to be a limit point of $S$ -- that's the _definition_ of what a limit point means!